# change value of css on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some colors that when clicked I want to change the value of some css.

I want to change the color css value of this css :

```
article .teleprompter p
{
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color:white;

}
```

The html:

```
  <div class="swatch concrete" onClick="javascript:changeBTC('#95a5a6')"></div>
```

This is the java script I use for a similar function . This one changes the background color:

```
<script>
function changeBGC(color)
{
document.getElementById("teleprompter").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
</script>
```

Would it make a difference in JavaScript code if the css was in a separate style sheet?

Comment: Change `.style.color` to your color. Also you should target the valid element which is the paragraph in this case.

Comment: In that case, please post the full HTML. Your CSS says `.teleprompter` (class) but JS says `getElementById`. Do you have the same value as class name and id for the element.

Comment: @Harry why do you need the full html ?

Comment: Your JS should just work fine and thats why I am guessing your problem could be elsewhere. At the moment we cannot recreate the issue you are probably having. So you may have to post all the relevant code or create a simple demo explaining it.

Comment: In your javascript try adding `color + '!important'` when you are changing the color of text.

Comment: @Harry how would the js work fine ? I want to change the <p> o the teleprompter class

Comment: @JamieAdamas: If that is the case, it is not coming out clearly in the question. JS would work in the sense that it would change the background color of the element with id as `teleprompter`.

Comment: This question is pretty unclear. You should post the real markup to determine how many `<p>` are nested within the `.teleprompter`. Are they direct descendants or not? Where's your current `changeBTC()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't add `javascript:` in `onclick` code - the borwser already knows it is javascript! You only need to add `javascript:` to an `<a href>` to tell the browser it is script rather than a URL:

So you just need this:

```
<div class="swatch concrete" onClick="changeBTC('#95a5a6')"></div>
```

or you could do this if you wanted to use a link:

```
<a class="swatch concrete" href="javascript:changeBTC('#95a5a6')"></a>
```

Comment: Even with the `javascript:` it should work fine. Atleast, it does for me in Chrome and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is `changeBGC`, but you're executing `changeBTC`. Replace `changeBTC('#95a5a6')` with `changeBGC('#95a5a6')`

Answer (score 0):

It will not make a difference if the css was in a seperate file as long as you are refering the css file in your html page. 
Moreover in css you are refering the object as class in css (.teleprompter) and in javascript you are refering the object with id (getElementById). So either use **id** in both the places or **class** in both the places

Comment: give an id to the p element eg.let para be the id of the p element. In the javascript function use

document.getElementById('para').style.color = "green"